# Realm continuously crashing on arm64-v8a architecture

Tags: android, realm

I am splitting for different CPU architecture.

```
ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 31, 'armeabi-v7a': 32, 'arm64-v8a': 33, 'mips': 34, 'x86': 35, 'x86_64': 36]
```

Realm is crashing in devices which have `arm64-v8a` like **Galaxy S7 Edge** &  **Note 5**.

**Stack trace from Google Developers Console -**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/hero2qltetmo/hero2qltetmo:6.0.1/MMB29M/G935TUVU2APC8:user/release-keys'
Revision: '15'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 31837, tid: 31872, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> com.app <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x570048
    x0   0000007f938d1c08  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000000000000000  x3   0000000000000000
    x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
    x8   0000000000000001  x9   0000007f99bde000  x10  0000007f99bdd000  x11  0000000000000000
    x12  0000007f9d88a888  x13  0000000000000001  x14  0000000000000000  x15  0000007f99cfc68c
    x16  0000007f846e3820  x17  0000007f9d814038  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000000000570048
    x20  0000007f997a9660  x21  0000007f984a8e00  x22  0000007f938d1c00  x23  0000000012cc51c0
    x24  0000000012cc5160  x25  0000000012d70640  x26  0000007f843f3480  x27  0000000000000000
    x28  0000000000000001  x29  0000007f843f33f0  x30  0000007f845c702c
    sp   0000007f843f33f0  pc   0000007f845c702c  pstate 0000000060000000

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000000c602c  /data/app/com.app -1/lib/arm64/librealm-jni.so
    #01 pc 00000000013a1af4  /data/app/com.app- /oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x94b000)
```

**Stack trace from Crashlytics**

```
Caused by java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
io.realm.internal.SharedGroupManager. (SharedGroupManager.java:43)
io.realm.BaseRealm. (BaseRealm.java:76)
io.realm.Realm. (Realm.java:126)
io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate (Realm.java:246)
io.realm.Realm.createInstance (Realm.java:231)
io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache (RealmCache.java:114)
io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance (Realm.java:181)
com.app.display.ActivitySplash$1.doInBackground (ActivitySplash.java:58)
com.app.display.ActivitySplash$1.doInBackground (ActivitySplash.java:52)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:287)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: The latest version of realm I updated the app yesterday itself - 0.88.3

Comment: @mjosh it sounds like a bug, i created a github issue to track it https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2611 . Is it possible to share you APK with us? We can test with 64bits devices. Let's continue the conversation on github.

Comment: @beeender I have sent a mail to Kenneth at Realm help.